# date off by 1 day due to different timezones in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timezone

my default timezone is (UTC + 8:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore and the computations is working fine but when I change my pc timezone to (UTC-6:00) Central Time (US & Canada) the result of is off by 1 day.

In (UTC + 8:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore Time the output from this.referenceMilestones[key]) is  2022-10-20 and after using the getRefMileStoneDate function the result is

#result which is correct

```
refMilestoneDate-- Thu Oct 20 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)
```

But in timezone  (UTC-6:00) Central Time (US & Canada) , the result if off by one day

#result which is wrong , it is now 19 which is supposed to be 20

```
refMilestoneDate-- Wed Oct 19 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Any idea how we can solve this one that the date should be consistent regarding of the timezone ? Thanks for helps and ideas.

#Code

```
const refMilestoneDate = this.getRefMileStoneDate(calculateFields[i].referenceMilestoneName);

 console.log('refMilestoneDate--', refMilestoneDate)

  getRefMileStoneDate(key:string):Date{
    if (this.referenceMilestones && this.referenceMilestones[key]){
      console.log(' ' , this.referenceMilestones[key])
      return new Date(this.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.referenceMilestones[key]));
    }
    return null;
  }

 convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(dateString: any) {
    if (dateString) {
      const dateObject = new Date(dateString);
      return dateObject.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }).replace(/\//g, '-');
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript, especially at the client side, typically assumes you're working in local times. You probably want to work exclusively in UTC via the various UTC methods available in the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

Otherwise, you'll want to look into use a date library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) which will allow you precise control of time zones both when parsing timestamps and when formatting them for display.

Comment: do you have an example how we can implement or based on your suggestion Sir that I could test on my code ? Thanks.

Comment: No I can't provide that. There's a lot of missing information such as what does this.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD operate on, are these date objects referenceMilestones, where do they come from (db query, json, etc.)

Comment: Are you trying to work strictly with a date and not a time, such as a birthday or a due date?

Comment: not stricly , the goal is what ever the date selected regardless of the timezone should be the date that would be saved on the database.

Comment: Then I think you need to store those items in the database with a UTC time zone, and send them to the client as UTC time zone usually with "+00:00" appended to the end if an ISO 8601 time string. Then use the UTC functions mentioned in the answer when displaying it.